# Insert fails due to "column not allowed here" error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a beginner with SQL. I have created 4 tables and added data to my SHIP table. I am having some issues with inserting data into the CRUISE table. I get the error message at the bottom.

I have researched and can not figure out what i am doing wrong. Is there an issue with my sequence and/or trigger that is not allowing me to do this or is my syntax in the CREATE TABLE CRUISE causing the error? Everything i have done has been successful up until trying to insert the first column into the CRUISE table.

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE SHIP 
( Ship_Name VARCHAR2(100) PRIMARY KEY,
Ship_Size INTEGER,
Ship_Registry VARCHAR2(50),
Ship_ServEntryDate INTEGER,
Ship_PassCapacity INTEGER,
Ship_CrewCapacity INTEGER,
Ship_Lifestyle VARCHAR2(40),
CONSTRAINT Size_ck CHECK (Ship_Size > 0),
CONSTRAINT Registry_ck CHECK (Ship_Registry IN ('Norway','Liberia','The Netherlands','Bahamas'))
)

CREATE TABLE CRUISE (
Cruise_ID INTEGER Primary Key,
Ship_Name VARCHAR(100),
Cruise_DeptDate DATE NOT NULL,
Cruise_DeptCity VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
Cruise_Duration INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (Ship_Name) REFERENCES SHIP(Ship_Name)
)

CREATE TABLE PASSENGERS (
Pass_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Pass_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Pass_City VARCHAR(80),
Pass_Telephone VARCHAR(15),
Pass_NextOfKin VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE RESERVATIONS (
Pass_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
Cruise_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
Res_TotalCost NUMERIC(9,2),
Res_BalanceDue NUMERIC(9,2),
Res_SpecialRequest VARCHAR(30),
Res_Room VARCHAR(10),
FOREIGN KEY (Pass_ID) REFERENCES PASSENGERS(Pass_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Cruise_ID) REFERENCES CRUISE(Cruise_ID),
CONSTRAINT Cost_ck CHECK (Res_TotalCost >= 0),
CONSTRAINT BalanceDue_ck CHECK (Res_BalanceDue >= 0),
CONSTRAINT SpecialRequest_ck CHECK (Res_SpecialRequest IN ('Vegetarian','Vegan','Low salt','Gluten free','Kosher','Other'))
)
```

The sequence/trigger is an attempt to auto number Cruise_ID.

```
Create SEQUENCE cruise_id_sq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cruise_id_t
BEFORE INSERT 
ON CRUISE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if(:new.Cruise_ID is null) then
SELECT cruise_id_sq.nextval
INTO :new.Cruise_ID
FROM dual;
end if;
END;

ALTER TRIGGER cruise_id_t ENABLE;
```

Inserting into SHIP is okay....

```
INSERT INTO SHIP
(Ship_Name, Ship_Size, Ship_Registry,Ship_ServEntryDate, Ship_PassCapacity,Ship_CrewCapacity,Ship_Lifestyle)
Values ('Carribean Princess',142000,'Liberia',1000,3100,1181,'Contemporary');

INSERT INTO SHIP
(Ship_Name, Ship_Size, Ship_Registry,Ship_ServEntryDate, Ship_PassCapacity,Ship_CrewCapacity,Ship_Lifestyle)
Values ('Carribean Sunshine',74000,'Norway',1992,1950,760,'Premium');

INSERT INTO SHIP
(Ship_Name, Ship_Size, Ship_Registry,Ship_ServEntryDate, Ship_PassCapacity,Ship_CrewCapacity,Ship_Lifestyle)
Values ('Ship of Dreams',70000,'Liberia',2004,1804,735,'Contemporary');

INSERT INTO SHIP
(Ship_Name, Ship_Size, Ship_Registry,Ship_ServEntryDate, Ship_PassCapacity,Ship_CrewCapacity,Ship_Lifestyle)
Values ('Sunshine of the Seas',74000,'The Netherlands',1990,2354,822,'Luxury');
```

Inserting into CRUISE fails...

```
INSERT INTO Cruise
(Ship_Name, Cruise_DeptDate,Cruise_DeptCity,CruiseDuration)
Values ('Sunshine of the Seas',25-may-15,'Miami',10);
```

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - INSERT INTO Cruise (Ship_Name,
>   Cruise_DeptDate,Cruise_DeptCity,CruiseDuration) Values ('Sunshine of
>   the Seas',25-may-15,'Miami',10) Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 35
>   Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
>   00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Oracle thinks `25-may-15` is a column. Put quotes around it.

Comment: @muratgu, Oracle would only think that's a column if it were double quoted `"25-may-15"`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name We are in agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle thinks that `25-may-15` is the expression 25 minus `may` minus 15. In looking up the value for `may` Oracle finds that there is nothing there. Thus the error.

You can, but probably don't want to, quote it like so, `'25-may-15'`. This will make a string that may or may not be implicitly converted to a date, depending on the settings of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and or `NLS_TERRITORY`.

To form a date independent of session setting one can use the [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) function with explicit date format, `to_date('25-may-15', 'DD-Mon-YY')`. Another option is a [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062), `date '2015-05-25'`, which is always `YYYY-MM-DD` no matter the session settings..